# Create a new variable of concatenated values of other columns using dplyr::mutate and a vector of choice columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate

I have this dataframe:

```
vehicles <- tibble(vehicle = c("Car", "Car", "Motorbike"),
                   color = c("Red", "Black", "Blue"),
                   speed = c("Low", "High", "High"))
```

| vehicle | color | speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Red | Low |
| Car | Black | High |
| Motorbike | Blue | High |

I would like to create a new column that pastes the categorical values of columns that I choose based on a vector.

For instance, if I want to create a categorical column based on vehicle and color, I would do:

```
vehicles %>% mutate(category = paste(vehicle, color, sep = "_"))
```

Which would give me:

| vehicle | color | speed | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | Red | Low | Car_Red |
| Car | Black | High | Car_Black |
| Motorbike | Blue | High | Motorbike_Blue |

However, I want to embed this code into a function, so that **the columns to paste are determined by a character vector provided by the user.**

E.g., user chooses `choices = c("vehicle", "color", "speed")`. But dplyr's tidy evaluation does not allow me to do `vehicles %>% mutate(category = paste(choices, sep = "_"))`, because that would simply create a column vector full of "vehicle_color_speed" values. How would I then create something with the same result as:

```
vehicles %>% mutate(category = paste(vehicle, color, speed, sep = "_"))
```

but using the choices vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rlang::syms`:

```r
library(dplyr)
choices = c("vehicle", "color", "speed")
vehicles %>% 
  mutate(category = paste(!!!rlang::syms(choices), sep = "_"))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  vehicle   color speed category           
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>              
1 Car       Red   Low   Car_Red_Low        
2 Car       Black High  Car_Black_High     
3 Motorbike Blue  High  Motorbike_Blue_High
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I see that rlang::syms returns a list of symbols based on the provided vector. However, what's the functionality of `!!!` in dplyr (inthis particular case)? Does it unpack the list for the expression?

Comment: Yes, kinda. It is similar to `do.call`  in base R. Check [here](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
vehicles %>%
  unite(category, all_of(choices), remove = FALSE) %>%
  relocate(category, .after = last_col())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  vehicle   color speed category           
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>              
1 Car       Red   Low   Car_Red_Low        
2 Car       Black High  Car_Black_High     
3 Motorbike Blue  High  Motorbike_Blue_High
```